# Slow audio-video sync drift when merging wav and mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, synchronization

I have an `mp4` file with only a single video stream (no audio) and a `wav` audio file that I would like to add to the video using `ffmpeg`. The audio and the video have been recorded simultaneously during a conference, the former from a mixer output on a PC and the latter from a digital videocamera.

I am using this `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i incontro3.mp4 -itsoffset 18.39 -i audio_mix.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac final-video.mp4
```

where I'm using the `-itsoffset 18.39` option since I know that 18.39s is the video-audio delay.

**The problem I'm experiencing** is that in the output file, while the **audio** is perfectly in sync with the **video** at the beginning, it **slowly drifts out of sync during the movie**.

The output if `ffprobe` on the video file is:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'incontro3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:47:22.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 888 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 886 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

and the `ffprobe` output for the audio file is:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'audio_mix.wav':
  Metadata:
    track           : 5
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:46:32.20, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

I'm using the latest `ffmpeg` Zeranoe windows build [git-9591ca7](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20160525-git-9591ca7-win64-static.7z) (2016-05-25).

Thanks in anticipation for any help/ideas!

---

<strike>**UPDATE 1:** It looks like the problem is upstream the video-audio merging, and could be in the concatenation and conversion of the `MTS` files generated by the video camera into the `mp4` video. I will follow up as I make any progress in understanding...</strike>

---

**UPDATE 2:** The problem is not in the initial merging of the `MTS` files generated by the camera. Or, at least, it occurs identically if I merge them with `cat` or with `ffmpeg -f concat`

---

**UPDATE 3:** Following @Mulvya's suggestion, I observed that the drift rate is constant (at least as far as I can tell judging by eye). I also tried to superimpose the A/V tracks with another software, and the drift is exactly the same, thereby ruling out `ffmpeg` as culprit. My (bad) feeling is that the issue could be related to the internal clocks of the digital video camera and the laptop used for audio recording running at slightly different rates (see [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14529/sync-separate-audio-to-videobad-camera-audio-free-nle-recommendations) the report of an identical issue I just found).

Comment: How much drift and which becomes late - audio or video?

Comment: Audio slowly drifts some seconds behind video in about 30min

Comment: Can you load a sample of the audio & video just long enough to observe the drift?

Comment: @Mulvya I could try but the original video is a 2GB `MTS` file, and I'm unsure if cutting/converting it in some way already introduces sync problems. I was searching around and I think I will try to plug in the `-af aresample=async=1000` option to see if it allows `ffmpeg` to match the audio to the video timestamps. Although I'm not so sure about what that option really does...

Comment: I believe that won't work with WAV. Only with audio formats which contain timestamps, and if those timestamps faithfully represent recording time. 2GB is too big, so I'd suggest checking if the rate of drift is constant i.e. if it's 2 seconds out of sync after 5 minutes, is it 4 seconds async after 10 mins. That will elucidate the nature of the aysnc. If it's irregular, then either the video or audio is dropping frames during recording.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Mulvya, I will try to check the drift rate and follow up

Comment: @Mulvya as far as I can tell, the drift rate is constant. But I'm updating the question with another hypothesis in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Since the drift rate is constant, you can use a combination of FFmpeg filters to retime the audio.

```
ffmpeg -i audio_mix.wav -af asetrate=44100*(10/9),aresample=44100 retimed.wav
```

Here, `44100*(10/9)` indicates the actual no. of samples that represent 1 second of sound i.e. if after 100 seconds of playback of the original WAV, the audio just heard is the 90th second, then the sample consumption rate should be increased by `10/9`. That would make for an unconventional sample rate, so aresample is added to resample it back to a standard rate.